# Hibernate implicit entity restrictions

Tags: hibernate

Is any way to add implicit restriction to entity in HQL? For example when we query list with hql "from Client" we need select only thouse clients, that have some particular system id. System id itself depends on user session. So we need this query to be actually converted to "from Client where systemId=:systemId" although we didn't specify it in original query

Comment: well, why don't you define the query with the WHERE clause?

Comment: This solution is too hard with our architecture, as we have a lot of HQLs scattered throughout the application. Using filtering promise to be less painful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hibernate Filter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/filters.html) is what you're after...

> In order to ensure that you are
>   provided with currently effective
>   records, enable the filter on the
>   session prior to retrieving employee
>   data:
>
> ```
> Session session = ...;
> session.enableFilter("effectiveDate").setParameter("asOfDate", new Date());
> List results = session.createQuery("from Employee as e where e.salary > :targetSalary")
>          .setLong("targetSalary", new Long(1000000))
>          .list();
> ```